# How in the world do I do this problem on joint variation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can anyone help me with this simple grade 12 math question on joint variation? I'm stuck, I'm the WORST at word problems.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Remember that in general "$F$ varies jointly as $x$ and $y$" means $F=kxy$ for some constant $k$. 
Here you have $q$ in place of $F$, $t$ in place of $x$, and $v^2$ in place of $y$. Can you figure it out from there?